# RegEx to match a valid JavaScript namespace

Tags: javascript, regex

What would be the regular expression to match a correct any-depth JavaScript namespace?

**Valid Entries**

- `a`
- `a.b`
- `$a._b.$$c.__d`
- `a_$09.b_$09.c_$09`

So basically, JavaScript open-name variables joined by dot, and each separate name can contain `a-z`, `A-Z`, `_`, `$` and `0-9`, but cannot start with `0-9`.

**Invalid Entries**

- `1a` - cannot start with a digit
- `abc.1a` - a sub-name cannot start with a digit also
- `.a` - cannot have a leading dot
- `a.` - cannot end with a dot

I have tried this one: `^([a-z$_][a-z$_0-9]*\.?)*[^\.]$`, which while bans the trailing `.`, allows any extra symbols in the end, such as `,`, which is invalid.

Comment: like [Regex online](https://regex101.com/r/Z9oiSy/1)?

Comment: @Sphinx Just tried, it works, though I prefer shorter: `/^[a-z][0-9a-z\$\_]*(\.[a-z][0-9a-z\$\_]*)*$/i` :)

Comment: @Sphinx Ops, just found a problem - it doesn't allow leading `$` or `_`, which it should, just like for any open-name JavaScript variable ;)

Comment: uses `[a-zA-Z\_\$]` instead of `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: [`^[_$a-zA-Z][\w$]*(\.[a-zA-Z][$\w]*)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/Z9oiSy/3) is a simplified version of @Sphinx's regex

Comment: @emsimpson92 examples where it fails: `a.$b`, `a._b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uses `^[a-zA-Z\$\_][0-9a-zA-Z\$\_]*(\.[a-zA-Z\$\_][0-9a-zA-Z\$\_]*)*$`

because **\w** matches any word character (equal to **[a-zA-Z0-9_]**),

so as @emsimpson92  said, you can have one simplified version:

`^[a-zA-Z\$\_][\$\w]*(\.[a-zA-Z\$\_][\$\w]*)*$`

for the shortest version so far as @vitaly-t commented (removed unnecessary escaping), it will be:

`/^[a-z$_][$\w]*(\.[a-z$_][$\w]*)*$/i`

[Regex Online](https://regex101.com/r/Z9oiSy/4)

Comment: I think this one is then the most elegant: `/^[a-z\$\_][\$\w]*(\.[a-z\$\_][\$\w]*)*$/i`.

Comment: Actually, you do a lot of escaping that's not needed. So the ultimate shortest version is: `/^[a-z$_][$\w]*(\.[a-z$_][$\w]*)*$/i`, if you want to update the answer ;)

Comment: @vitaly-t, Hah, thanks for the suggestions. it is my bad habit, add escaping for all special characters...